# Reinforcement learning (q-learning) evaluation

Tags: python

I am new to reinforcement learning, and currently I am working on a small q-learning project but I am a little confused?
1- what is the testing phase of a q-learning model, and how do we make a prediction (try it on single, unseen data) with it? at this point I have created the needed function for choosing action and getting reward ...etc, and I was able to run a 10000 episodes, but I believe this is the training phase.
2- what are the metrics that we use to say that our model has learned and performed well or not? something like accuracy in classification scheme for example.

Thank you.

Comment: Q function is your metrics by definition. If it measures expected reward, you want to maximize it. If it's expected cost, you want to minimize it. You may add some proprietary metrics on top, but it totally depends on the scenario that you learn. E.g. number of moves, number of doing "bad things", etc, it's up to you

Comment: Test episode is also up to you. If you learn chess, it's ok to play the same episodes as in training (chess is chess). If it's a level of a game, you can hold out a single level, if it doesn't deviate too much from other training levels